# Laravel mySQL view return by specific ID

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

So I am quite new to Laravel, and I have a situation, where I am trying to gather data from a pivot table (contains 2 foreign keys only) in order to retrieve data from other tables.

Before everything, I'd like to note, that word "campaign" is the same as "box". Simply it differs in database and front.

I have multiple boxes, that contains specific gifts.

I have set the URL of the box to be something as such: http://127.0.0.1:8000/box/1
http://127.0.0.1:8000/box/2
etc..
I have done so, by simply using a button with the {id}:

```
<a href="box/{{$item->id}}" class="btn btn-dang btn-xs">View the box</a>
```

My plan is, to print out only that specific boxes gifts (right now, all boxes print out all gifts).

I have tried to use the ->where option within my function, although, it seems that I can't try equaling to the campaigns ID.

Incorrect code:

```
function box(){
        $data = array(
            'list'=>DB::table('campaigns_gifts')
            ->join('gift_items', 'gift_items.id', '=', 'campaigns_gifts.gift_foreignK')
            ->select('gift_items.*')
            ->where($campaign_foreignK = '{id}')
            ->get()
        );
        return view('DBqueries.boxView', $data);
    }
```

My question is, how can I specifically return data, that only belongs to that specific box, since I am not able to use mysql where option.

For reference, these are the database tables:[image: campaigns_gifts]

[image: gift_items]

Basically, I would need to match my URL's id with campaign_foreignK

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, yout need to start to use Laravel Eloquent Models.

But doing by your way (the hardest):

You need to create a route in web or api, something like that:

```
Route::get('/box/{id}', [BoxController::class, 'view']);
```

Then you need to put this function on your controller:

```
function view($id){
 /**
* You can do it by 2 ways:
* 1 - Do a where in the result of DB query (the bad way)
*/

$list = DB::table('campaigns_gifts')
    ->join('gift_items', 'gift_items.id', '=', 'campaigns_gifts.gift_foreignK')
    ->select('gift_items.*')
    ->where($campaign_foreignK = '{id}')
    ->get();
$list = (array)collect($list)->where('abc', 123);

/**
* Or the second way (the best is to use the Eloquent, but using DB the following is the best)
* 1 - Get the relations:
* Is git_items id the key for gift_foreignK ? i'm supposing that is it! so....
*/

$giftsIds = array_values((array)DB::select("select * from campaigns_gifts where campaign_foreignK = $id"));
$giftsIdsString = implode($giftsIds, ',');
$list = (array)DB::select("select * from gift_items where id in ($giftsIdsString)");

return view('DBqueries.boxView', ['list' => $list]);
}
```